# Как записать в переменную состояние checkBox, находящегося в cellWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, checkbox, findchildren

В моём `tableWidget` создаются `checkbox` на `widget` и вставляются в него через `.setCellWidget`.

Как мне считать с этого виджета состояние `checkbox` и передать в переменную `bool`?

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import test


class tabletest(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, test.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации нашего дизайна
        self.filltab(self.tableWidget_6)
        self.filltab(self.tableWidget_7)
        self.filltab(self.tableWidget_8)
        self.filltab(self.tableWidget_9)

    def filltab(self, table):
        row_count6 = table.rowCount()
        print(row_count6)
        for row in range(row_count6):
            check_box = self.create_checkbox()
            table.setCellWidget(row, 3, check_box)

    def create_checkbox(self):
        Widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        pCheckBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        pLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(Widget)
        pLayout.addWidget(pCheckBox)
        pLayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        pLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        Widget.setLayout(pLayout)
        return Widget


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = tabletest()  # Создаём объект класса TaskManager
    window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png"))
    window.show()  # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()  # и запускаем приложение


if __name__ == '__main__':  # Если мы запускаем файл напрямую, а не импортируем
    main()  # то запускаем функцию main()
```

**test.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(917, 400)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);\n"
"")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 120, 471, 171))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tableWidget_6 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab)
        self.tableWidget_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 471, 151))
        self.tableWidget_6.setStyleSheet("color: red;\n"
"background-color: rgb(151,63,175);")
        self.tableWidget_6.setObjectName("tableWidget_6")
        self.tableWidget_6.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget_6.setRowCount(4)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(0, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(0, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(1, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(1, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(1, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(2, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(2, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(2, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(3, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(3, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(3, 2, item)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tableWidget_7 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.tableWidget_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 471, 151))
        self.tableWidget_7.setStyleSheet("color: red;\n"
"background-color: rgb(151,63,175);")
        self.tableWidget_7.setObjectName("tableWidget_7")
        self.tableWidget_7.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget_7.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setItem(0, 2, item)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.tableWidget_8 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_3)
        self.tableWidget_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 471, 151))
        self.tableWidget_8.setStyleSheet("color: red;\n"
"background-color: rgb(151,63,175);\n"
"")
        self.tableWidget_8.setObjectName("tableWidget_8")
        self.tableWidget_8.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget_8.setRowCount(2)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setItem(0, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setItem(0, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setItem(1, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setItem(1, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setItem(1, 2, item)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.tableWidget_9 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_4)
        self.tableWidget_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 471, 151))
        self.tableWidget_9.setStyleSheet("color: red;\n"
"background-color: rgb(151,63,175);")
        self.tableWidget_9.setObjectName("tableWidget_9")
        self.tableWidget_9.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget_9.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setItem(0, 2, item)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Задача"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Дата"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Состояние"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Статус"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget_6.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget_6.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "zzz"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "02-12-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(0, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Ожидание"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(1, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "xxx"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(1, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "11-12-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(1, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Ожидание"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(2, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "ccc"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(2, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "18-11-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(2, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Просрочено"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(3, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "vvv"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(3, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "22-02-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(3, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Выполнено"))
        self.tableWidget_6.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("Form", "Все"))
        item = self.tableWidget_7.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_7.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Задача"))
        item = self.tableWidget_7.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Дата"))
        item = self.tableWidget_7.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Состояние"))
        item = self.tableWidget_7.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Статус"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget_7.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget_7.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget_7.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "vvv"))
        item = self.tableWidget_7.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "22-02-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_7.item(0, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Выполнено"))
        self.tableWidget_7.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("Form", "Выполнены"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Задача"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Дата"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Состояние"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Статус"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget_8.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget_8.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget_8.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "zzz"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "02-12-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.item(0, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Ожидание"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.item(1, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "xxx"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.item(1, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "11-12-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.item(1, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Ожидание"))
        self.tableWidget_8.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("Form", "Ожидание"))
        item = self.tableWidget_9.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_9.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Задача"))
        item = self.tableWidget_9.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Дата"))
        item = self.tableWidget_9.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Состояние"))
        item = self.tableWidget_9.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Статус"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget_9.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget_9.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget_9.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "ccc"))
        item = self.tableWidget_9.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "18-11-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_9.item(0, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Просрочено"))
        self.tableWidget_9.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("Form", "Просрочены"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Метод записи данных в БД

```
def update(self):
    for row_count in range(self.tableWidget_6.rowCount()):
        bool = self.tableWidget_6.cellWidget(row_count, 3).isChecked() #!!!!!(попытка присвоить переменной значение с виджета с чекбоксом)
        #cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO database (Check)"
        #            f"VALUES ('{bool}')")
        print('Данные записаны')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick Добавил пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkBoxs = widget.`**`findChildren`**`(QtWidgets.QCheckBox)[0]`

**findChildren** - возвращает всех дочерних элементов этого объекта с заданным именем, которое может быть приведено к типу T, или пустой список, если таких объектов нет. Отсутствие аргумента имени приводит к совпадению всех имен объектов. Поиск выполняется рекурсивно, если в параметрах не указан параметр FindDirectChildrenOnly.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren , https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QObject.html?highlight=findchildren#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QObject.findChildren

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# from test import Ui_Form                  
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(917, 400)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);\n"
"")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 120, 471, 171))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tableWidget_6 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab)
        self.tableWidget_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 471, 151))
        self.tableWidget_6.setStyleSheet("color: red;\n"
"background-color: rgb(151,63,175);")
        self.tableWidget_6.setObjectName("tableWidget_6")
        self.tableWidget_6.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget_6.setRowCount(4)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(0, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(0, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(1, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(1, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(1, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(2, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(2, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(2, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(3, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(3, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_6.setItem(3, 2, item)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tableWidget_7 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.tableWidget_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 471, 151))
        self.tableWidget_7.setStyleSheet("color: red;\n"
"background-color: rgb(151,63,175);")
        self.tableWidget_7.setObjectName("tableWidget_7")
        self.tableWidget_7.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget_7.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_7.setItem(0, 2, item)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.tableWidget_8 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_3)
        self.tableWidget_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 471, 151))
        self.tableWidget_8.setStyleSheet("color: red;\n"
"background-color: rgb(151,63,175);\n"
"")
        self.tableWidget_8.setObjectName("tableWidget_8")
        self.tableWidget_8.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget_8.setRowCount(2)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setItem(0, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setItem(0, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setItem(1, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setItem(1, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_8.setItem(1, 2, item)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.tableWidget_9 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_4)
        self.tableWidget_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 471, 151))
        self.tableWidget_9.setStyleSheet("color: red;\n"
"background-color: rgb(151,63,175);")
        self.tableWidget_9.setObjectName("tableWidget_9")
        self.tableWidget_9.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget_9.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_9.setItem(0, 2, item)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Задача"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Дата"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Состояние"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Статус"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget_6.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget_6.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "zzz"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "02-12-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(0, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Ожидание"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(1, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "xxx"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(1, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "11-12-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(1, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Ожидание"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(2, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "ccc"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(2, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "18-11-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(2, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Просрочено"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(3, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "vvv"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(3, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "22-02-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_6.item(3, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Выполнено"))
        self.tableWidget_6.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("Form", "Все"))
        item = self.tableWidget_7.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_7.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Задача"))
        item = self.tableWidget_7.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Дата"))
        item = self.tableWidget_7.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Состояние"))
        item = self.tableWidget_7.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Статус"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget_7.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget_7.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget_7.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "vvv"))
        item = self.tableWidget_7.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "22-02-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_7.item(0, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Выполнено"))
        self.tableWidget_7.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("Form", "Выполнены"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Задача"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Дата"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Состояние"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Статус"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget_8.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget_8.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget_8.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "zzz"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "02-12-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.item(0, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Ожидание"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.item(1, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "xxx"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.item(1, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "11-12-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_8.item(1, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Ожидание"))
        self.tableWidget_8.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("Form", "Ожидание"))
        item = self.tableWidget_9.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget_9.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Задача"))
        item = self.tableWidget_9.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Дата"))
        item = self.tableWidget_9.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Состояние"))
        item = self.tableWidget_9.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Статус"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget_9.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget_9.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget_9.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "ccc"))
        item = self.tableWidget_9.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "18-11-2021"))
        item = self.tableWidget_9.item(0, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Просрочено"))
        self.tableWidget_9.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("Form", "Просрочены"))


#class TableTest(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
#                         vvvvvvv                <---- это у вас скрытая ошибка # !!!
class TableTest(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  
        
        self.filltab(self.tableWidget_6)
        self.filltab(self.tableWidget_7)
        self.filltab(self.tableWidget_8)
        self.filltab(self.tableWidget_9)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Click me', self)
        self.button.resize(100, 40)
        self.button.move(570, 340)
        self.button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(151, 151, 175);")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.run_button)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def filltab(self, table):
        row_count6 = table.rowCount()
        for row in range(row_count6):
            check_box = self.create_checkbox()
            table.setCellWidget(row, 3, check_box)

    def create_checkbox(self):
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        pCheckBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        pLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(widget)
        pLayout.addWidget(pCheckBox)
        pLayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        pLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        widget.setLayout(pLayout)
        return widget

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def run_button(self):
        self._update()

    def _update(self):
        print('\ndef _update(self):')
        
        for row_count in range(self.tableWidget_6.rowCount()):

#            # !(попытка присвоить переменной значение с виджета с чекбоксом)        
#            bool = self.tableWidget_6.cellWidget(row_count, 3).isChecked() 

            _bool = False
            widget = self.tableWidget_6.cellWidget(row_count, 3)
            checkBoxs = widget.findChildren(QtWidgets.QCheckBox)[0]
            if checkBoxs:
                _bool = checkBoxs.isChecked()
            
            #cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO database (Check)"
            #            f"VALUES ('{_bool}')")
            
            print(f'checkBox в строке {row_count}: {_bool}')
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = TableTest()                    
    window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png"))
    window.show()  
    app.exec_()    


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сколько искал информации по проблеме - ничего о findChildren не слышал...
Да, это то, что мне нужно) Спасибо Вам!

Comment: @Regulirovshik пожалуйста.